# How to add constraints to parameters in pymc3 model?

Tags: python, pymc3

I followed the first tutorial in pymc3 concerning a linear regression. I tried to adapt it to a different function that is :

```
Y_obs = log (x+a)^2 / (x-c)^2
```

As you can see it could be preferable that `c` was negative. Thus I wonder how to define the prior for c with negative values. For example, an `HalfNormal` distribution but with only the negative values instead of the positive ones.

More generally I wonder if it is possible to set bounds to parameters ?

For example, using Stan (or pyStan) in the model set up you can write :

```
parameters {
    real<lower=0, upper=1> p;
}
```

to set p \in [0, 1].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a variable that is constrained to the negative values you can define a positive one and take the negative of that:

```
a = pm.HalfNormal('a', sd=1)
b = -a
```

If you want to access the value in the trace you can tell pymc3 to store it by wrapping it in a `pm.Deterministic` (probably not *that* useful in a simple case like this...)

```
a = pm.HalfNormal('a', sd=1)
b = pm.Deterministic('b', -a)
```

Use `pm.Bound` to add arbitrary constraints:

```
NegNormal = pm.Bound(pm.Normal, lower=-np.inf, upper=0)
a = NegNormal('a', mu=0, sd=1)
```

But keep in mind that this does not change the density of the normal distribution, so it won't integrate to 1 anymore. Usually this doesn't matter, as the difference in the logp will be a constant, and we don't care about constants for most things. If it does matter (this could be if the lower or upper bound is a variable) you can fix this by defining your own distribution with `pm.DensityDist` (same problem in stan by the way, although it has support for truncated distributions with the T[a,b] syntax).